# Casting Ridge Regression to OLS

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, regression, least-squares

OLS solves the problem below and has closed-form solution $\hat{\beta} = (X^\top X)^{-1}Xy$
$$
\min_\beta \|y - X\beta\|^2.
$$
Ridge regression solves the problem below and has closed-form solution $\hat{\beta} = (X^\top X + \lambda I)^{-1}Xy$
$$
\min_\beta \|y - X\beta\|^2 + \lambda \|\beta\|^2.
$$
Is it correct to say that a ridge regression problem is just an OLS problem with the following structure:
$$
\tilde{y} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    y\\
0
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
\tilde{X} = \begin{pmatrix}
    X \\
    -\sqrt{\lambda}I
\end{pmatrix}
$$
since
$$
\|y-X\beta\|^2 + \lambda\|\beta\|^2 = \|\tilde{y} - \tilde{X}\beta\|^2 
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have the system

$$y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{11} + \ldots \beta_px_{p1}$$
$$y_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{12} + \ldots \beta_px_{p2}$$
$$\vdots $$
$$y_N = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1N} + \ldots \beta_px_{pN}$$
$$0 = \sqrt{\lambda}\beta_0$$
$$0 = \sqrt{\lambda}\beta_1$$
$$\vdots$$
$$0 = \sqrt{\lambda}\beta_p$$

Then you can write the new data matrix as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X\\
\pm \sqrt{\lambda}I\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the observations as you proposed. Note the arbitrary sign. The square will make the negative sign positive agian.